# Django multiple model inheritance, django-push-notifications

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I am writing a back end for a mobile app using Django 1.8. The `django-push-notifications` lib provides the `GCMDevice` model. The problem is I already have a `Device` model with some mandatory field and some logic I don't want to lose.

What I wanted to do is to inherit whole `GCMDevice` functionality and adjust them to my Device model(which btw inherits another mixin providing spatial data fields, with custom object Manager set which I want to keep). I read about 3 different django model inheritance ideas but none of them seem to solve my problem (keeping managers, provide `django-push-notifications` functionality, keeping my `Device` model fields). Maybe OneToOne association will do the work?

IDEA:

```
class Device(MyMixin):
    gcm_device = models.OneToOneField(GCMDevice)
    my_other_field = models.TextField()

    def send_message(self, payload):
        self.gcm_device.send_message(payload)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why it is necessary to inherit? Could composition be a substitute for what you are trying to do by inheritance?

----------------- Edited answer -----------------

```
class Device(models.Model):
    ...
    gcm_device = models.OneToOneField(GCMDevice)
```

I have given the most simple case, you could make the GCM device your primary key as well.

Comment: No reason at all, I thought it's the only solution. Ok, now I know general idea about composition but still don't have idea how to apply this to django models? Could you provide some example?